# filtering query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, filtering

i already write a query for filtering in laravel like

```
    $data = DB::table('products')->DISTINCT('modalid')->DISTINCT('brandid')->select('rimdiameter','modalid','modalname1','modalname2','image1','brand','minprice','maxprice')
->when($centre_bore, function($query,  $centre_bore){
    $query->where('hubbore','>=',$centre_bore);
})->when($boltptn, function($query, $boltptn) {
    $query->where('boltpattern',$boltptn);
})->when($diameter, function($query, $diameter) {
    $query->where('rimdiameter',$diameter);
})->when($width, function($query, $width) {
    $query->where('rimwidth',$width);
})->when($frontwid, function($query, $frontwid) {
    $query->where('rimwidthfront',$frontwid);
})->when($construct, function($query, $construct) {
    $query->where('construction',$construct);
})->when($color, function($query, $color) {
    $query->where('modalname2',$color);
})->when($brand, function($query, $brand) {
    $query->where('brand',$brand);
})->get();
```

it working but , rimdiameter=22 , rimwidth=11 and rimwidthfront=9 the user is selectd value, in above condition there is no data but i wand the query work like rimdiameter=22 , rimwidth=11 and rimdiameter=22, rimwidthfront=9 this how to write the query for this result?the other fields are impotent some time that values are null so i used when ,how to implement the above requirement in my query..

Comment: I think you should use `where()` clause instead of `when()`

Comment: @hacker315 i dint understand

Comment: Please see answer below. See if it helps.

Comment: you didn't mention it in your question..

Comment: Can you please share an example of request, what you get and the expected value. Your question is not very clear

Comment: @hacker315 sry for that now i will update my question

Comment: @ChristopheHubert  ajax request is for a click eg:- first click the diameter show that result and click width show width and diameter resut and click front width show  width and diameter and front width result ...color,brand,price....

Comment: @hacker315 any changes i try your answer in my query but in single condition show null result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
$data = DB::table('products')->DISTINCT('modalid')->DISTINCT('brandid')->select('rimdiameter','modalid','modalname1','modalname2','image1','brand','minprice','maxprice')
->where(function ($query) use ($diameter,$width,$frontwid) {
    $query->where('rimdiameter', '=', $diameter)
           ->where('rimwidthfront', '=', $frontwid)
        ->orWhere('rimdiameter', '=', $diameter)
        ->where('rimwidth', '=', $width);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
`where('rimwidth','=',$width)`

cause where function take three parameters:

1. columns name
2. symbol
3. values